# Дан одномерный массив целых чисел А. Создать новый массив В, занеся в каждый элемент минимальный среди всех предыдущих элементов массива А

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
  if (i==0) B[i] = A[i];
  else {
    if (A[i-1] < B[i-1]) B[i] = A[i-1];  
    else   B[i] = B[i-1];
}
void main() {
setlocale(0, "");
int n, i
 
int *A;
cout « "Введите размер массива:" « endl;
cin » n;
A = new int[n];
cout « "Введите массив A:" « endl;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
cin » A[i];
}
```

Помогите с этим заданием, пожалуйста.
Дан одномерный массив целых чисел А. Создать новый массив В, занеся в каждый элемент минимальный среди всех предыдущих элементов массива А (в первый элемент заносится первый элемент А). Подсчет минимального элемента из предыдущих реализуется в виде функции.

Comment: Попытайтесь сделать сами, покажите вашу попытку (код), и скажите, что именно не получилось.

Comment: Ищете минимум как обычно. Каждый раз, когда обновляете переменную с текущим минимумом, заносите это значение в масссив B

Comment: Начнем с того, что `for(i=0; i<n; i++) ...` должно быть внутри какой-то функции.

Answer (score 1):

Модное решение в одну строчку:

```
int *B = new int[n];
std::inclusive_scan(A, A + n, B, [](int x, int y){return std::min(x, y);});
```

Но черта с два у вас такое примут. :Р Если хотите нормальное решение, попытайтесь что-то сделать сами и покажите свой код, будем чинить.

Comment: А что не примут? Не соображают чтоль?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Не поверят, что сам написал. Или скажут "использовать только что, что было на лекциях". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Да, возможно, стандарт С++17 не примут.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Можно заменить `inclusive_scan` на `partial_sum`, который был всегда. Но вряд ли что-то поменяется.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >>  n;
    int* A = new int[n], *B = new int[n];
    cin >> A[0];
    int m = A[0];
    B[0] = A[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];

        if (m > A[i]) m = A[i];

        B[i] = m;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << B[i] << " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: большое спасибо